# Comparing the extracted year of two dates

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle11g

I am trying to compare the years of two dates. 
Extracting them isn't the problem, however, I can't seem to get the comparison working, which I find odd because I know I did the exact same thing a few months back without any problems. I hope someone can shed some light on the reason for the error occuring.

A few infos regarding my columns:

- The keydate column is NUMBER(11,0); sample of raw data in column: `20140531`
- The fieldvalue column is VARCHAR2(100 CHAR); sample of raw data in column: `19.07.2017`

My query throws an `ORA-01722 invalid number` exception:

```
SELECT identifier, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE(a.keydate, 'yyyymmdd')) AS keydate, 
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE(a.fieldvalue, 'dd.mm.yyyy')) As fieldvalue 

FROM My_Table a 
WHERE a.fieldindex = 15 AND a.fieldvalue IS NOT NULL AND identifier <> -1 
AND TO_NUMBER(fieldvalue) >= keydate
Order by identifier;
```

I'd expect the query to store `2014` and `2017` in keydate / fieldvalue, because of the `ÈXTRACT(...)` statement. These are numbers just fine, so I don't get why this exception is thrown, as I explicitly convert the fieldvalue to a number... Can you give me any hints as to what goes wrong here?

Edit: Might have found the cause of the error... I tend to forget that you can't use the variables you select in your where clause :/ Now the error makes sense and I'll try to fix it by building another query around it. Thanks for the help so far.

Edit2: My take on using the original query as a subquery, hoping to fix the issue. However, I am getting a new error message now `ORA-01830 date format picture ends before converting entire input string`, which I find even more strange considering I don't do any date conversion operations in the parent query and the subquery works fine on its own. I also tried other variations, i.e. explicitly converting fieldvalue and keydate to NUMBER, CHAR, DATE in the parent queries where clause, however, the error message remained:

```
SELECT identifier, keydate, fieldvalue
FROM
(
SELECT identifier, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE(a.keydate, 'yyyymmdd')) AS keydate, 
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE(a.fieldvalue, 'dd.mm.yyyy')) As fieldvalue 
FROM My_Table a 
WHERE a.fieldindex = 15 AND a.fieldvalue IS NOT NULL AND identifier <> -1 
)   
WHERE fieldvalue >= keydate
ORDER BY identifier;
```

Comment: TO_NUMBER(fieldvalue) >= keydate - '19.07.2017' is not a number

Comment: The real question is: why are you storing dates as `number` or `varchar`. You should dates in a `date` (or `timestamp`) column, never store them in anything else.

Comment: @Multisync '2017' is stored in `fieldvalue`. I extract it in the SELECT statement. '2017' should be a number?!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Well, it's the data model I have to work with

Comment: You said: "fieldvalue is VARCHAR2(100 CHAR); sample: 19.07.2017" - TO_NUMBER('19.07.2017') raises the exception because '19.07.2017' is not a number. I'm not talking about your select list (it's ok)

Comment: Ah sorry, I was unclear then. It was supposed to be samples for what is stored in the columns pre extraction not post. I'll edit accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
AND TO_NUMBER(fieldvalue) >= keydate
```

with

```
AND case when identifier <> -1  
         then EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE(a.fieldvalue, 'dd.mm.yyyy')) 
         else null end
    >= EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TO_DATE(a.keydate, 'yyyymmdd'))
```

The expressions in your SELECT list are calculated after all other clauses like FROM, WHERE, GROUP BY, HAVING (except ORDER BY which is calculated the last)

So when Oracle calculates conditions in WHERE it doesn't know anything about your expressions in SELECT list. And it does not see column aliases from SELECT in WHERE clause

Comment: Thanks, I also just remembered that. Unfortunately I can't just use the extract function in the where clause, because there are other entries with a different format in the fieldvalue column (they got the identifier -1). That's why I did the extract in the select clause in the first place, because I need to make sure that only values with dd.mm.yyyy format are going into the extract statement. Otherwise I get the ORA-01830 exception. I just tried creating another SELECT statement around the whole thing, but also get an error in that case :(

Comment: @daZza I've updated my answer. With the new condition you can remove "AND identifier <> -1" from your WHERE

Answer (score 0):

```
select extract(year from to_date(keydate,'RRRRMMDD')) keydate,
extract(year from to_date(regexp_substr(fieldvalue,'[^.]+', 1,3)||regexp_substr(fieldvalue,'[^.]+', 1,2)||regexp_substr(fieldvalue,'[^.]+', 1,1),'RRRRMMDD')) fieldvalue
from t123;
```

Comment: This code will extract your year regexp_substr is an regular expression function in oracle,for user to bring fieldvalue to read in form of date. –  Dharmesh Porwal 41 mins ago